# How to collect average time in block data

Tags: anylogic

My goal is to understand how much time throughout my model an agent is waiting (in the queue of a seize block) moving (through moveto) and working (delays). Originally I thought I could gather this from the built in database which has exactly this data in the flowchart_stats_time_in_state_log, however, I would like to collect this data throughout a parameters variation. Therefore, I need a way to collect this data and write it to a data set or excel. The problem is I can not find how to access block statistics.

Maybe my approach is incorrect and I should instead collect data on my various agents.

Comment: You should collect it in the agents themselves, yes. Use the flowchart block code boxes ("on enter"...) to record the correct times. Accumulate, aggregate and output. But you need to do this manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your agent you can have a variable which saves the time the agent enters the seize block, and thus also the queue. And then you can save the delta between the enter time and the time it seizes a unit (i.e. it exists the internal queue of the seize block) and then save this calculated time to a statistic object.

[image]

At the end of the simulation you can then easily write this data to the DB or to Excel, or to a txt file for example

[image]

Comment: If I have a new agent entering seize queue where an agent is already waiting, will it overwrite the agent.timeEnter() that was set by the previous agent or is data stored on a agent by agent basis?

Comment: I have created a new question specifically for the comment above. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71675942/how-to-not-let-time-collections-overwrite-one-another

Comment: The agent you are referring to in that line of code is for that specific  instance of that Agent type. And the variable lives inside the agent. So it is unique for each agent entering