# How to not let time collections overwrite one another

Tags: anylogic

I am currently logging times in various blocks using this method seen below in order to collect the average time spent in a block. This is an example for one block. The problem is the mean is incorrect due to times where 15 patients are waiting in the queue because the variable `timeEnterExamRoom` room will constantly be updated with every new patient coming in, not providing a true reading of the mean. Is there a way to ensure that this timing scheme is attributed to individual patients and not just reading any patient that enters the block and that seizes a room?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you are saying is not correct. The `timeEnterExamRoom` is an agent specific variable. So no matter how many agents enter the queue, each will have its own value for that variable. They do not overwrite each other. When you type `agent.` it means you are accessing the specific agent's unique variable.

Comment: When I run this on a standard simulation as a test, I am seeing discrepancies between the statistics I collect and those of the built in database. However, I believe it is because the number of agents in a block is not counted if the agent does not spend any time in it (i.e. if the seize is conducted right away without queueing) whereas the statistics blocks count everything

Comment: Yes, the statistics block counts everything...